# Loop through checkboxes to see if the content is set to "" in Visual Basic

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have two pages current in my wpf project. Depending on an option that is selected on the first page when I have the user go to the second page I want to hide some of the check boxes that I have in a grid. I have 4 different options on the first page each requiring a different amount of checkboxes on the second page.

I think what I need is a For loop to iterate over the grid and check to see which boxes have an empty string as their content.

Below is what I imagine what it would be like - although I am unsure. I am new to Visual Studio, Visual basic and WPF so I could be doing this completely wrong.
This is not code I have tried as I do not know the proper syntax for it - this is only my logic

```
For each checkBox in secondPage.grid
If checkBox.content = "" Then
checkBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
End if

End For
```

**How do I hide the unneeded group boxes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Page1 pass it's option selected in some form say String. Get this value passed from Page1 in Page2 constructor and do some action based on it.
In example below support Page1 passes string "1" indicating option1 was chosen, then we can set visibility of CheckBox1 accordingly. You can do it for other checkboxes too.

```
Class MainWindow 
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Form1Option = ... (passed from Form1)

        Dim Form1Option As String
        Form1Option = "1"

        CheckBox1.Visibility = IIf(Form1Option = "1", System.Windows.Visibility.Visible, System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)

    End Sub

End Class
```